# Viewpager2 and ChilfFragment

Tags: android-viewpager, child-fragment

I have a fragment page that I manage with Vievpager2. I have 3 fragment pages in it. My click on the second fragment page affects the previous page, and the areas I click on are using the same service.

How can I prevent the click on the second page from affecting the first page?